# iFrame - Issue exiting full screen

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<iframe class="test" width='600' height='270' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='yes'  src='//dailysport.pw/c1.php#player'></iframe>
```

i'm using a live sports website as an example.

The problem is that when you play and enter full screen and then exit, the text  "(Descarga Brave para eliminar la publicidad : https://brave.com/?ref=dai031)"   at the top of the web is visible.

Am I doing something wrong in css?

Comment: That text is inside iframe or is it your own text?

Comment: I don't see any CSS in your example.

Comment: @Justinas the text is inside the iframe

Comment: @RobJarvis I meant, should I add something in css?

Comment: If it's bug inside website itself, then you can't do anything.